# Unable to create new Q# project using Microsoft Quantum Development Kit

Tags: visual-studio-2017, quantum-computing, q#

Having just installed the [Microsoft Quantum Development Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/development-kit), creating a new **Q#** project fails with the obscure message:

> Argument can't be null: Parameter name: node.

(I am using a clean install of Visual Studio 2017 Community, with latest updates applied.)

Screen shot illustrating how to reproduce the problem:
[image]

And the resultant error message:

[image]

**Does anyone know what causes this error, and how it may be resolved?**

Comment: Just to get through all the first questions: you've restarted Visual Studio, rebooted your computer, etc?

Comment: @speckledcarp Yes, tried all of that; unfortunately no change.

Comment: Cool. Have you tried downloading one of the example projects at https://github.com/Microsoft/Quantum and seeing if you can open/run it?

Comment: @speckledcarp Downloading the sample files from the github link you provided in your previous comment allowed me to open the samples.  I can compile and run those samples without issue.  I still cannot create new solutions, but Microsoft released a new update to Visual Studio today that I will install and report if it changed anything.  Thanks!

Comment: Even after installing updates, the only way for me to use Q# is to open an existing project/solution.  New projects cannot be created.  I can't even add a Q# project (or even a source file) to an existing solution.

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. That makes it seem like you've got all the runtime libraries you need, but that somehow the integration with VS is broken. Reinstall VS? It might also be some sort of platform specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue (also with VS Community 2017 and Q#) - a repair of VS fixed the issue for me and it's worked fine since.